# C++ GUI write to textBox while using backgroundWorker

Tags: user-interface, c++-cli

I am trying to write to a textBox while having a loop on backgroundworker. I tried using Invoke/BeginInvoke however I couldn't do it. How can I change it to make it work? Here is my code below, thanks in advance.

```
 delegate void backgroundWorker1_DoWorkDelegate(Object^ sender, DoWorkEventArgs^ e);
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
if (textBox1->InvokeRequired)
        {
                backgroundWorker1_DoWorkDelegate^ action = gcnew backgroundWorker1_DoWorkDelegate(this, &MyForm::Worker);
                
                this->BeginInvoke(action);
            }

            else
            {
                textBox1->Text = "a";

            }     ...  }

        void Worker(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^ e)
        {
            textBox1->Text = "a";
        }
```

Comment: Is this managed c++ driving winforms?

Comment: yes, I found similar examples of c# but couldn't implement it to c++